# VS Code, Git commits, and Electron non context-aware native modules

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron, git-for-windows

I'm using Git 2.26.2.windows.1 on Windows 10 with VS Code 1.45.1 as the commit log message editor

Today I used `git commit` and edited the commit log message in VS Code, and then exited VS Code (saving the changes in the process). Git finished the commit but first I got all sorts of Electron warnings from VS Code:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
[main 2020-06-05T15:08:31.739Z] update#setState idle
(node:1924) Electron: Loading non context-aware native modules in the renderer process is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future, please see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397 for more information
...
[main 2020-06-05T15:09:01.747Z] update#setState checking for updates
[main 2020-06-05T15:09:01.776Z] update#setState idle
```

What does this mean? My fear: does this mean Electron is removing something that VS Code uses to work as the editor for Git, so that soon Git will remove VS Code support? (I don't know enough about Electron and the VS Code implementation to interpret this fully.)

Answer (score 3):

This message, if it comes from VS Code's stdout log, just means that VS Code currently uses a feature the Electron team plans to deprecate. Since VS Code is built using Electron, this is an issue which must be fixed by the VS Code developers (and they're most likely already aware of it) and does not mean that you'll end up with an editor which is not working. Since VS Code bundles Electron, as long as it bundles a version it can work with (which it most likely will; wouldn't make sense otherwise), you can work with VS Code.

Also, Git technically does not "support" VS Code, you just told Git to use VS Code to edit your messages.